# MacOS crashes after running python turtle

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I run the following code on my Mac(MacOS 10.14.6):

```py
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

and then my computer crashed and I had to start it manually(there was no error message printed). Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Running from interpreter or .py script?  Version of Spyder?

Comment: using jupyter notebook/spyder, python 3.7.3

Comment: I ask for the spyder version as this error was common before spyder 3.3.6.

Comment: sorry... the spyder version was 3.6.3. So the solution was to upgrade the spyder to the newest version? But this issue happened when I used jupyter notebook as well.

Comment: Interesting, does it work when running it as a `.py`?

Comment: No. running `.py` file in the terminal still causes the crash.